# How to install multiple apps in Software Center (Similar Behavior of Synaptic)

Tags: 11.10, software-center, synaptic

I wish to select multiple apps in Software Center and THEN tell it to install them. Same as the behavior of Synaptic where I select multiple ones and the click Install. This saves MANY clicks for me and much time. Is there an option for this.

The multiple selection also includes the ability to select as Synaptic does, doing double click on an app. Is there an option for this in Software Center. For example, to double click VLC and have it install automatically without going to the information window about VLC and clicking on Install. It is nice but very annoying if am suppose to install via GUI 20, 30 apps.

As a side note I actually like the new changes and look and feel of the Software Center now, but the intuitive and more friendly nature of Synaptic with details like this is what is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to select multiple apps and then install them at a time in software-center. There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/929209) filed to have this feature in the software-center but there is no visible progress towards this.

---

As an alternative, if you are using 12.04 or would be using 12.04 when it is released, I suggest you try [lubuntu-software-center](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lubuntu-software-center)  [image: Install lubuntu-software-center], which supports installing multiple apps at a time.

To install it, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```

As you browse the software, you can click on *Add to the Apps Basket* if you want to install it later. After you have selected the applications that you want to install, go to *Apps Basket* and click on *Install Packages*. This way, you can install multiple apps at a time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

software-center will queue the installs of the packages, so you don't have
to wait for one operation to finish before installing the next.

I don't know of a way to install a lot with one click, but the above feature
means that double-clicking the ones you want will have them all install.